# Content type add page misalignment in drupal 8

Tags: nodes, 8

In D8 in all the content type adding pages the settings which display on the bottom of the page have been misaligned , refer the pic below .

[image]

How can i fix this , Is it related to any style issues ?

**UPDATE**

In `garland` theme that portion is coming properly but have some other style issues in it .
[image]

Comment: yes its a style issue. This type of issue may occured if you have installed such module that has same style code as the add page. You can override it using current themes style.css

Comment: Is this the default admin theme? (Seven) or did you create/downloaded  an admin theme?

Comment: The default theme used is bartik